# Decimal rounding off to 2 places instead of 3 in ASP.Net Core API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a model property defined as

```
public decimal? GrossWeight { get; set; }
```

In my database, the column is created as `GrossWeight decimal(18, 3)`.

When I am sending data via POSTMAN, I am passing 3 decimal digits like `1.961`, but at the time of saving the data is saved as `1.960`. Save happens using a stored procedure and I cross checked the property in the stored procedure as `decimal(18,3)`.

Any reasons why this could happen or possible solutions?

Have checked the entire project for `GrossWeight` property to check any round offs happening, but found nothing.

Comment: Do you have any browser culture settings or do you have UI culture configuration somewhere within your project?

Comment: nothing of that sort.

Comment: So you would prefer to keep `.960` three decimal precidence right? Is it for perticular scenario or full application?

Comment: I want to save .961 and not .960. For full application

Comment: Alright, thanks for your response and explanation

Comment: Please have a try the solution, it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any reasons why this could happen or possible solutions?

**Issue Reproduced:**

I have successfully reproduced your issue. Which is causing because of your defination in entity framework column property. Your SQL server knows its precision but entityframework doesn't. As you can see below:

[image]

**SQL Server Investigation:**

But when I tried to insert directly from `SQL server` worked as expected.

[image]

**Solution:**

In your model you have to defined explicitely using annotation as below:

```cs
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 3)")]
        public decimal? GrossWeight { get; set; }
```

**Note:** As EF doesn't know the [`Precision and Scale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#precision-and-scale) therfore, it changes the precision. If you put 1.967 it will change the precision autometically. In addition, `[Precision(.., ..)]`  can do the same, nevertheless, we outght to define length in that case. So Annotation is hassle free.

**Final Output:**

[image]

For further details you can [`check this official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#precision-and-scale)

Comment: I removed the ASP.Net tag because the problem is not related to it. It's not a question about how ASP.Net works. Please don't re-add it. That's tag spamming.

Comment: Okay, alright, No problem, I got your point. Thanks.

Comment: I thought, if same problem percist who are using asp.net core along with entityfremework core so they can refer this.

Comment: I am trying this out on an existing application, cleaning and rebuilding the code still gives the same output. Any reasons you can think of? Defined property as [Precision(18, 3)]

Comment: First try with `[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 3)")]` , make sure nothing cached, event clear visual studio cache. If doesn't work then try with ` [Precision(18, 3)]` though both does same. If still problem encountered, then need to check your dbcontext configuration, asp.net core and EF version.

Comment: Did all 3. Tried both. Also, tried adding OnModelCreating, Cleared cache, wasnt working with EFCore 6, upgraded to EF Core7 (to double clear stuff) but still doesnt work. Any other guesses to what could be the reason?

Comment: Well, thanks for your response, in this scenario, need to have a look on your full relevant code snippet for instance, model, controller, and how you are getting the data from view, and SQL server version. Model also need to include how you configure dbcontext. So that it will be convenient to investigate further.