# I'm unable to save a decimal number in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

How do we save a decimal number in ASP.NET Core MVC ? Every time I try, it keeps saying "The premium cover must be a number". See the screenshot:

[image: Error Image]

This is the model

```
[Display(Name = "Premium Cover")]
public decimal Premium { get; set; }
```

I have tried putting ranges, expressions etc. I'm still unable to save a decimal value.

This is the html

```
<div class="col-6 mb-2">
    <label asp-for="Member.Premium" class="control-label pt-2" style="font-size:18px"></label>
    <input asp-for="Member.Premium" id="premiumrate" class="form-control" value="@Model.Member.Premium.ToString("F2").Replace(",", ".")"  />

    <span asp-validation-for="Member.Premium" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I have tried several things like putting step='any' on html, I have tried putting data format string, range, regex expression on the model but still didn't work.

Comment: have you tried using `.` (dot) instead of `,` (comma) for a decimal separator?

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided?  Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 0):

> How do we save a decimal number in ASP.NET Core MVC ? Every time I
> try, it keeps saying "The premium cover must be a number"

Based on your code snippet and description it might be happend due to two main reasons. First of all, entity framework doesn't know about its data type or possibly because of your `default browser culture`. However, we can customize it as per the requirement.

Apart from this not sure why you are using `@Model.Member.Premium.ToString("F2").Replace(",", ".")".` You can ommit this and can try following steps:

If Data type doesn't recognized:

```cs
    [Display(Name = "Premium Cover")]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
    public decimal Premium { get; set; }
```

**Note:** [[Precision(18, 2)]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#precision-and-scale) also can work here. Make sure, in your database data type generated as decimal. You can [check document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#column-data-types)

If browser UI culture caused Issue:

**Program.cs:**

```cs
var defaultCulture = "en-US";
var ci = new CultureInfo(defaultCulture);
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."; // Defining my preferrence for number
ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";

// Configuring Number Seperator Using Localization middleware
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ci),
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        ci,
    },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        ci,
    }
});
```

**Note:** As you can see in `NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` I am setting my preferrence for seperator. You are open to use anything you want, any kind of charaters. Please consider the order as well while placing the code in middleware. Best use would be end of your `current middleware`. As following:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

In addition, you can also [refer to this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74739864/decimal-rounding-off-to-2-places-instead-of-3-in-asp-net-core-api/74740842#74740842) in case above solution doesn't work for you.

**Note:** If you would like to know more details, you could check our official document below.

1. [Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)
2. [The "." custom specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-1)
3. [Current UI culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-7.0#the-current-culture-and-current-ui-culture)